# Back end for iOS app with relational databases

Tags: ios, relational-database, backend

I am currently trying to build an ios application that will need to be able to retrieve and store data in a remote relational database. I have investigated using RestKit for the front end, which seems adequate. I have experience developing with both mysql and php, though I am not sure where to start in getting a web server to send information that is not html. (php enhanced html, that is)

I would appreciate any input on where I might get started. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP to query a mySQL database on my server and format the response as XML which I then parse in the app.
Here is a PHP example from my server....This also sends a size response to allow the App to track the download completion percentage and a file name response too.  Also, if the database is empty, it will send a dummy record.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/text"); 

//get the values from the url query string
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];
$db = $_GET['database'];
$dbhost = 'localhost';

//create connection to mysql or tell user something has gone wrong
$connection = mysql_connect( $dbhost, $user, $pass ) or die('Could not connect to MySQL');
//select database or tell user something has gone wrong
mysql_select_db( $db ) or die('Could not select database');


// Construct and run query.
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM itemInfo WHERE itemStatus = "active" ORDER BY itemSortKey ASC';
    //echo $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('<result>fail</result>');

    $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "<bodyimage>\n"; 


    while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $xml_output .= "\t<storeitems>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<itemSortKey>" . $record['itemSortKey'] . "</itemSortKey>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<itemDesc>" . $record['itemDesc'] . "</itemDesc>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<itemPrice>" . $record['itemPrice'] . "</itemPrice>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<productID>" . $record['productID'] . "</productID>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field1>" . $record['field1'] . "</field1>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field2>" . $record['field2'] . "</field2>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field3>" . $record['field3'] . "</field3>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field4>" . $record['field4'] . "</field4>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<dateCreated>" . $record['dateCreated'] . "</dateCreated>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<dateModified>" . $record['dateModified'] . "</dateModified>\n"; 

    // Escaping illegal characters 
    //$row['text'] = str_replace("&", "&", $row['text']); 
    //$row['text'] = str_replace("<", "<", $row['text']); 
    //$row['text'] = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $row['text']); 
    //$row['text'] = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $row['text']); 
    //$xml_output .= "\t\t<text>" . $row['text'] . "</text>\n"; 

        $xml_output .= "\t</storeitems>\n"; 

        //add this record to the output
        //$output = '|facilityname|' .$record['facilityname'] . '|/facilityname||customername|' . $record['customername'] . '|/customername||imageurl|' . $record['imageurl'] . '|/imageurl|';
        //print $output;
    }
    $xml_output .= "</bodyimage>";

    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="storeitems.xml"');
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen ( $xml_output )); 

    // redundent.....$xml_output .= "</bmrcontrol>";

    //echo strlen( $xml_output );
    //the next statement relates if there are NO lines in the table - it sends a message
    if ( strlen( $xml_output ) == 61 ) {
        $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "<bodyimage>\n"; 

        $xml_output .= "\t<storeitems>\n";
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<itemSortKey>aaaa</itemSortKey>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<itemDesc>Store Items Missing</itemDesc>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<itemPrice>0.0</itemPrice>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<productID>blank</productID>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field1>.</field1>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field2>.</field2>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field3>.</field3>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<field4>.</field4>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<dateCreated>2012-02-13 09:03:49</dateCreated>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<dateModified>2012-02-13 09:03:49</dateModified>\n"; 

        // Escaping illegal characters 
        //$row['text'] = str_replace("&", "&", $row['text']); 
        //$row['text'] = str_replace("<", "<", $row['text']); 
        //$row['text'] = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $row['text']); 
        //$row['text'] = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $row['text']); 
        //$xml_output .= "\t\t<text>" . $row['text'] . "</text>\n"; 

        $xml_output .= "\t</storeitems>\n"; 
        $xml_output .= "</bodyimage>";
    }

    echo $xml_output; 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        //mysql_close($connection);
    }
    else
      die('<result>fail</result>');
      //mysql_close($connection);
?>
```